# MSBuild, CreateItem to ItemGroup to binplace a target to multiple folders

Tags: msbuild, itemgroup, createitem

Short-story: I have a list of  with an attribute called true. I want to copy all of these files, to a list of folders, say defined by ...

someFolder

To that end, here's what I'm doing today:

```
    <CreateItem Include="%(Reference.HintPath)"
                Condition="'%(Reference.Binplace)' == 'true'"
                AdditionalMetadata="DestinationFolder=$(DestinationForReferences)\%(Reference.BinplaceFolder)">
        <Output ItemName="Binplace" TaskParameter="Include" />
    </CreateItem>
```

I already have a target called Binplace which internally calls Copy. The problem is that  is a single element, and I don't know how I can call Copy on multiple of these items

And in my CSPROJ file, I do this:

```
    <Reference Include="MyCompany.Something.Something">
        <HintPath>$(LocalLibraryFolder)\MyCompany.Something.Something.dll</HintPath>
        <Binplace>true</Binplace>
    </Reference>
```

Comment: Sorry, read this three times and I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish, or what the problem is, could you add a bunch of additional detail to your question?

Comment: Added more info, does this help?

Comment: Your text mentions a folder named "someFolder" but I don't see it referenced in the msbuild.  You need to show your "Binplace" target.  How does the "Binplace" target relate to the .csproj, is it in an imported targets file or a separate MSBuild project?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="1">
        <HintPath>$(LocalLibraryFolder)\1.dll</HintPath>
        <Binplace>true</Binplace>
        <BinplaceFolder>SubFolder1\SubFolder12</BinplaceFolder>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="2">
        <HintPath>$(LocalLibraryFolder)\2.dll</HintPath>
        <Binplace>true</Binplace>
        <BinplaceFolder>SubFolder2\SubFolder22</BinplaceFolder>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
     <LocalLibraryFolder>.</LocalLibraryFolder>
     <DestinationForReferences>.</DestinationForReferences>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CopyReferencedBinaries"
        Outputs="%(Reference.Identity)">    
     <ItemGroup>
          <SourceBinaryFullPath Include="%(Reference.HintPath)" />              
     </ItemGroup>
     <PropertyGroup>
          <SourceBinaryDir>$(DestinationForReferences)\%(Reference.BinplaceFolder)</SourceBinaryDir>
     </PropertyGroup>
     <MakeDir Directories="$(SourceBinaryDir)"
              Condition="!Exists('$(SourceBinaryDir)')"/>
     <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceBinaryFullPath)"
           DestinationFiles="@(SourceBinaryFullPath->'$(SourceBinaryDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
</Target>
```

Comment: you might have got this the other way round. I need my propertygroup to have a list of locations to deploy to. so <propertygroup><list>folder1</list><list>folder2</list></propertygroup>

Comment: And Binplacefolder just means drop this specific one elsewhere, but if this field is not present, drop it in all the locations mentioned by the propertygroup

Comment: @gaganuprasad I think you're confused how the PropertyGroup construct works. It only allows you to create distinct variables, not collections. The PropertyGroup tag simply allows you to group these properties into the same location in the xml and does not make them related in any other way.